# Is it possible to define a variable using another variable as its name

Tags: vb.net, winforms

The title may not accurately explain what i would like to do,

```
Dim BarName As String
For i = 0 To 20
  BarName = "Graph1Bar" And CStr(i)
  Dim BarName As New PictureBox
```

Next

I would like to create a new picture box for every instance of a for loop, and intend to change their names based on what iteration of the loop they were made in. Is there any way to do this?

I would also like to be able to call on these variables in a loop, like this:

```
For i = 0 to 20
  Graph1Bar(i).Height = 200
Next
```

I'm not sure if any of this is possible but some help or explanation would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Obviously, you can't have a variable be a string and a PictureBox.  Just set the Name property of the control to be able to reference it in the Controls collection of the parent container.  `Me.Controls("Graph1Bar20")...`

Comment: Four space indent to get code format at this site.

Comment: `Use a List(Of PictureBox)`. Iterate the List items, add a `Name`, set the `Size`, add to the `Form.Controls` collection. You can then use the List `Items` to *control* your Controls.

Comment: I think as you've shown in the second code block, just define an array (either fixed or dynamically resizable)

Comment: What you're suggesting would be useless anyway, because your variable would just be a local and cease to exist as soon as it goes out of scope.

Comment: `BarName = "Graph1Bar" And CStr(i)` will not work. The concatenation operator in vb.net is `&`. `BarName = "Graph1Bar" & CStr(i)` Turn on Option Strict.